# where can I download Techtalk.specflow.dll version 1.9.0 from?

Tags: nuget, specflow

where can I download Techtalk.specflow.dll version 1.9.0 from? As I am not able to install it using Install - package specflow. So, I think manually I need to install this. Can any one point me to right location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Visual Studio integration of SpecFlow is installed through Visual Studio Gallery: http://go.specflow.org/vsgallery

The runtime libraries and tools of SpecFlow (such as TechTalk.SpecFlow.Dll) should be installed through NuGet. Read more about this here: http://go.specflow.org/getting-started

The latest version of the VS integration is 1.9.1 while the latest version of the runtime is 1.9.0. The VS integration works also with previous runtime versions (including 1.9.0).

Answer (score 0):

And if you have another version, make sure you uninstall it first. I had 1.7 before installing 1.9. I had to install Nuget, powershell 2.0 along with 1.9 to make it work. But works fine with all that.